# Deletion of historic data in DW

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, ssis-2012

My company is using a SAP system as the data source and SQL server as a destination, and data is getting loaded from SAP to SQL table using SSIS.

Due to some unknown reason, I'm losing the old/historic data from the SQL table.

When the data gets archived in the SAP source database, will it trigger deletion of data in the SQL table when the SSIS package runs? Is there any way to stop data deletion in the SQL server table?

Thanks

Comment: No one outside your organization knows exactly how your SSIS logic works. You will need to ask the group/person that is responsible for this functionality.

Comment: `When the data gets archived in the SAP source database will it trigger deletion of data` it depends on the sort of data you are referring to, but generally the answer is **no**. When some business object is deleted (or archived) in SAP, is doesn't physically deleted from DB, just deletion indicator is set. But of course there can be exceptions from that rule